# How to use this function with ksh?

Tags: bash, ksh

I have the following function written in bash:

```
msend() { f=$(mktemp) ; rm -f $f ; if [ "$#" -gt 1 ] ; then ; d_zip=true ; zip $f "$@";filename="$f.zip" ; uuencode $f $filename | mail  -s "$filename" $mail_addr ; else ; uuencode $1 $1 | mail  -s "$1" $mail_addr ; fi ; }
```

this function works really well but the problem is that is written in bash, there are some terminals that only allow the usage of ksh I would like to translate this function to ksh, I would like to appreciate any help to overcome this situation.

I order to be more clear to use this function first you have to declare the following variable with your email:

mail_addr=YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS.

Comment: That looks like perfectly valid `ksh`, other than the suspicious looking semi-colon following the `then` keyword, which should be a syntax error in `bash` or `ksh`.

Comment: Yes I got an error that is why I would like to find a way to use this function in ksh,

Comment: @chepner If you kindly give me the function in ksh, I will accept and analyze your answer, its a little bit difficult to know that since I am more familiar with bash,

Comment: It may be written in bash, but it probably does not work in bash.

Comment: I know that this function works well since I use it a lot in terminals with bash,

Comment: @neo33 Please paste the code you actually run, without modifications. Don't try to rewrite it between running it and posting it. The function you posted does not work in bash because it contains semicolons after `then` and `else` which is invalid.

Comment: In fact, other than the two semi-colons mentioned already, this is valid POSIX shell; it should work identically in `bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `zsh`, etc. There is *nothing* `bash`-specific about it.

Comment: One thing to be careful of when moving between `bash` and `ksh` is local variables and function syntax.  In bash if you use `declare`, `local`, or `typeset` on a variable then it becomes local to the function with either syntax.  In ksh93 (using `typeset`), because local variables are not in POSIX, only the `function foo {` syntax supports locals, the `foo() {` (POSIX) syntax does not.

Comment: @cdarke I undertand, I appreciate the advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't crash in KSH 93u+:

```
msend() {
  f=$(mktemp)
  rm -f "$f"
  if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    d_zip=true
    zip "$f" "$@"
    filename="$f.zip"
    uuencode "$f" "$filename" | mail  -s "$filename" "$mail_addr"
  else
    uuencode "$1 $1" | mail  -s "$1" "$mail_addr"
  fi
}
```

The only oddities in your original post were spurious `;`. If this fails, it's related to the commands and arguments, not the syntax.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for, I really appreciate the support,